# winrt xaml independence from resolution

Tags: windows-runtime, screen-resolution

I'm working on Windows Store application basically developped for screen resolution 1366x768.
But for anothers resolutions I want to provide proportional adapting when all content is shown on the screen in the same proportions like it would be shown on the defined screen resolution (in my case 1366x768).

Is it possible to provide something like static resolution for application or may there is another ways to reach this?

Comment: So, if the user flips to 768x1366, what do you want? For the items on the screen to shrink to fit so that the original ratio is maintained?

Comment: Yes, every item with its size, margin, padding etc.

Comment: That's a very atypical Windows Store Application UX. Why wouldn't it reflow, snap, etc.?

Comment: I'm agree with you but customer thinks  it would be great))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a [`ViewBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox.aspx) and set the child element to 1366 width, 768 height. The contents should scale proportionally to whatever resolution the user's device is.

Answer (score 0):

Viewbox will use letterboxing (or empty space)  on the sides / top & bottom if necessary. [Multiple resolution issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477357/windows-8-metro-app-designing-for-multiple-resolution).

Better approach will be to use Adaptive layout. [Guidelines for scaling to screens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780612.aspx)

Sample implementation using Grid control can be found at [Multi-resolution apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)